# Why are there two brackets and not just one?

Tags: javascript

Hi there I am pretty new to this an have a weird thing happening: I have implemented instafeed into my magento page via

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/instafeed2.phtml"}}
```

I'm just wondering why there are two curly brackets instead of one. I know it's a noob question.

Comment: This is not JavaScript blocks, these are blocks by the magneto templating engine.

Comment: this is similar to echo in PHP.